# Cylinders and dyadic Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Let be $\Sigma_{+}=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ the space of sequences of $0^{'s}$ and $1^{'s}$. Consider the following surjective  application
$\phi:\Sigma_{+}\to [0,1]$ given  by
$$ \phi(\underline{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_i}{2^{i}} $$
where $\underline{x}=(x_i)$.

**My Problem**: I want to see that there is a correspondence between the cylinders of $ \Sigma_{+}$ and the dyadic intervals of [0,1].

**Obs 1:**  For me this has more or less clear that the image of $ \phi $ of a cylinder is a dyadic interval.

**Obs 2:** For me, a dyadic interval is an interval of the form $[\dfrac{k}{2^n},\dfrac{k+1}{2^n}]$ where $k=1,\ldots 2^n$

Comment: I rather think a dyadic interval has form $[1/2^{n+1}, 1/2^n]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve seen at least two definitions of *cylinder set*.

1. For each finite, non-empty $F\subseteq Z^+$ and function $\sigma:F\to\{0,1\}$ let $$B(\sigma)=\left\{x\in\Sigma_+:x\upharpoonright F=\sigma\right\}\;;$$ the cylinders are the sets $B(\sigma)$.
2. The cylinders are the sets $B(\sigma)$ defined in (1) for which $\operatorname{dom}\,\sigma$ is an initial segment of $\Bbb Z^+$.

Assuming that your definition is the second one, the result is straightforward.

Fix $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $m\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, and let $D=\left[\dfrac{m}{2^n},\dfrac{m+1}{2^n}\right]$. Let

$$m=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{b_{n-k}}{2^k}\;,$$ where each $b_k\in\{0,1\}$, so that $b_1\dots b_n$ is the $n$-bit binary representation of $m$, and let

$$\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{0,1\}:k\mapsto b_k\;.$$

I claim that $D=\varphi\big[B(\sigma)\big]$, i.e., that $\varphi(x)\in D$ if and only if $x_k=b_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$.

If $x\in B(\sigma)$, then

$$\varphi(x)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{x_k}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{b_k}{2^k}+\sum_{k>n}\frac{x_k}{2^k}=\frac{m}{2^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac{x_k}{2^k}\;,$$

and

$$0\le\sum_{k>n}\frac{x_k}{2^k}\le\frac1{2^n}\;,$$

so $\varphi(x)\in D$, and $\varphi\big[B(\sigma)\big]\subseteq D$. On the other hand, we know that

$$\left\{\sum_{k>n}\frac{x_k}{2^k}:x_k\in\{0,1\}\text{ for }k>n\right\}=\left\{\frac1{2^n}\varphi(x):x\in\Sigma_+\right\}=\left[0,\frac1{2^n}\right]\;,$$

so in fact $\varphi\big[B(\sigma)\big]=D$.

Comment: Can you explain me what does the notation  :$x\upharpoonright F$

Comment: @OEmpaladordeCabras: $x$ is a function from the positive integers to $\{0,1\}$; $x\upharpoonright F$ is its restriction to the set $F$. Some people write $x|F$ or even $x|_F$ for this.